# Pyspark change DF type from Double to Int

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

i am learning Spark and i am using CrossValidator. My code is:

```
# Let's just reuse our CrossValidator with the new dtPipeline,  RegressionEvaluator regEval, and 3 fold cross validation
crossval.setEstimator(dtPipeline)

# Let's tune over our dt.maxDepth parameter on the values 2 and 3, create a paramter grid using the ParamGridBuilder
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(dt.maxDepth, [2.0, 3.0]).build()

# Add the grid to the CrossValidator
crossval.setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)

# Now let's find and return the best model
dtModel = crossval.fit(trainingSetDF).bestModel
```

When i compile it i have this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Note that the `df` tag is for the Unix command by that name and has nothing to do with dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! maxDepth attribute must be integer, so in function addGrig we have touching [2.0, 3.0] for [2, 3].